# How to keep jquery ui datepicker in place (stick to the input control) while scrolling?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, uidatepicker

After reading a lot of on the subject I'm still in the dark about how to approach resolving the problem. To clarify problem, I want calendar to scroll altogether with input control associated and not to stay fixed at whatever screen position.
Here is image with no scroll: (that is what I want to preserve on scroll as well)
[image]

and here is image while scrolling : (that is not what I want)

[image]

Any tip would be greatly appreciated.
UPDATE:
Here is a [link](http://jsbin.com/ubahe5/110/edit#javascript,html,live) that closely portray the problem, I would like calendar to stick to the control while scrolling.

Comment: There might be something wrong with your set up, because http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/ in the demo the calendar stick to the input field while scrolling. Can you show some code?

Comment: seems like it has position:fixed instead of :absolute... any link?

Comment: thanks for response, I can not provide link as the site I'm working on is not public, sorry. @Joy I've noticed that myself and it confusing me even further!? The div containing datepicker is position absolute.

Comment: maybe setting up a http://jsfiddle.net with the esential markup?

Comment: Here is a link to essential markup: http://jsbin.com/ubahe5/109/edit#javascript,html,live

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the problem since datepicker disappear on scroll.

Comment: Here is a fiddle which recreates your problem, the problem occurs if the the container div's content height is greater than it's defined height and scrollbar appears, then when you scroll the calendar doesn't stick to the input as it has position absolute. http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/m6A5q/embedded/result/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am not sure if your's one is a scrollable div, but the problem occurring here is jQuery UI date picker doesn't move with HTML content when inside a scrollable div.

Here is a fiddle which demo http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/m6A5q/embedded/result/ demonstrating the problem. Click on input and try scrolling that div.

It's happening because jQuery UI create the calendar UI as position `absolute` `relative` to `document` or `window` not the container scrollable div. So when the scrollable div is scrolled main window's scrolling context isn't changed and hence the datepicker calendar doesn't follow other html element in that div.

So the solution can be to hide the calendar when that div is scrolled and it makes sense, if the input is not visible you can hide the datepicker calendar. So the updated code will be

```
var datePicker = $('#datepicker').datepicker();

$(".demo").scroll(function() {
  datePicker.datepicker('hide');
  $('#datepicker').blur();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  datePicker.datepicker('hide');
  $('#datepicker').blur();
});
```

It will hide the date picker when container div or window is scrolled. here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/m6A5q/2/

I am using the `$('#datepicker').blur();` because when user scrolls `.demo` calendar hides but the `input` is still focused, so when he scrolls back he can become confused. So as I blur it he will have to click on the `input` again and date picker will show up.

Comment: Thanks Joy, that was my solution originally but the developer that is in charge insists that calendar should stick to it's control. +1 for alternative solution

Comment: This is not the actual solution as the datepicker is hidden only when scrolling by the scrollbar (i.e) it is not hidden when we are scrolling by mouse without clicking anything