# jQuery Date picker not moving with page scroll

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using the standard jQuery UI datepicker ,However when i scroll the page the date picker remains fixed . Any ideas how to solve this ?

http://jsfiddle.net/jbK6a/3/

Regards,
Neil

Comment: Your background color also in white..not in black..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to keep jquery ui datepicker in place (stick to the input control) while scrolling?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638854/how-to-keep-jquery-ui-datepicker-in-place-stick-to-the-input-control-while-scr)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that the datepicker is **outside** the `div` with `overflow: scroll;`. If the datepicker was generated inside the container this wouldn't be a problem.

Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/jbK6a/15/

I placed the datepicker behind the input with the `beforeShow` event.

And I used `position: relative;` on the scrollable container so that de absolute element listens to the container.

Comment: @lealam Something is wrong with your datepicker.js, go ahead and use jQueryUI instead.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn't work if the user first scrolls then clicks the input. In this case, the calendar seems to be displaced upwards in proportion to how far you have scrolled, bringing the dialog on top of or above the input field.

Comment: if Parent element is absolutely positioned then using the solution in the answer along with :
beforeShow: _.bind(function (input, ui) {
                    var $absoluteParent = $(input).closest(".absoluteParent");
                    $absoluteParent.after($(input).datepicker('widget'));
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        ui.dpDiv.css({left:$absoluteParent.css('left') , top: $absoluteParent.css('top')});
                    }, 0);
                }, this),

Worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: i had to use `#ui-datepicker-div {
    top: 0 !important;
    left: 0 !important; 
}` along with the `beforeShow` to position the datepicker correctly

Answer (score 6):

With a little fiddling I managed to get the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/jbK6a/12/

Using this, the datepicker hides itself on page scroll. I believe there are jQuery methods to ascertain the scroll position and so with a bit more fiddling, you could then manually manipulate the datepicker and update its position based on this value...

**UPDATE**:
Just fiddled a bit and got: http://jsfiddle.net/jbK6a/18/ which scrolls the datepicker, but it's really messy, any number of things can break it especially other collapsible elements. Fortunately Sem has a far better and cleaner solution :)

(Thought I'd add my code anyway though)

Comment: Hiding on scroll is IMHO an elegant solution, too. +1

Answer (score 3):

To solve this problem in jQuery UI 1.11.4 I added a .bind() event to the end of the datepicker instantiation:

```
$("*selector*").datepicker({
  *settings*
}).bind('click',function () {
  $("#ui-datepicker-div").appendTo("*other-selector*");
});
```

In my case, the "other-selector" was $(this).closest('*the-date-input-parent*'). This picks up the single #ui-datepicker-div box (which jQuery UI places at the end of the DOM) and moves it to a location somewhere else within the document. This can be done for multiple datepickers on the same page.

The *other-selector* should have position: relative; set so that the absolutely positioned #ui-datepicker-div becomes positioned relative to the new parent. Once so, it scrolls just fine.

This solution was the easiest fix to this problem (though it took a lot of time and searching to come to this conclusion) and allowed the datepicker to work correctly on mobile devices and tablets where it would otherwise be unusable.

Comment: Note that you will likely want to set "top: 0 !important" (or similar) on the #ui-datepicker-div to ensure it remains fixed to the top of the new div.

Answer (score 2):

Use **daterangepicker** plugin and we have to add new option **parentEl**

```
 <div class="container">
        <h2>Modal Example</h2>
        <!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
            Open modal
        </button>

        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div class="modal" id="myModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">

                    <!-- Modal Header -->
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Modal body -->
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <input type="text" name="dates" value="01/01/2018 - 01/15/2018" />
                       

                    </div>

                    <!-- Modal footer -->
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('input[name="dates"]').daterangepicker({
                parentEl: $('#myModal'),
                showDropdowns: true,
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove height: 100% rule from html selector. That's solves problem.

Comment: Could you give us a working solution or example?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find any answers on this using Bootstrap and datepicker that was having an issue with the datepicker staying attached to the element when scrolling on a modal. This was my solution:

```
 var dateModals = (function() {
    'use strict';

    var currentInput = '';

    var setPos = function() {
        if (currentInput === '') return false;
        var $datepicker = $('.datepicker');
        var topPos = currentInput.offset().top + currentInput.outerHeight();
        if ($datepicker.hasClass('datepicker-orient-bottom')) {
            topPos -= $datepicker.outerHeight() + currentInput.parent('.date').outerHeight();
        }
        $datepicker.css('top', topPos);
    };

    var attachEvents = () => {
        $('.modal').on('scroll', function() {
            setPos();
        });

        $('.modal').on('click', '.date input.form-control', function() {
            currentInput = $(this);
        });
    };

    var initialize = (function() {
        attachEvents();
    })();

})();
```

If following Bootstrap & Datepicker syntax, this should play nicely.