# Bootstrap Datepicker scrolling issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Experiencing a strange scrolling issue on my website where the bootstrap datepicker calendar doesn't stay with the input box that its attached to. Tried my best to recreate it in a jsfiddle. (in the box scroll with your mouse wheel then click on the input box to view the calendar.) Im aware it doesnt appear in front but that isnt the issue, it was just for recreational purposes. You will notice that it doesn't scroll correctly with the input box which is what im trying to fix.

My original code was:

```
 $(".datepicker-input").each(function(){ $(this).datepicker();});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker-input" />
```

Script:

```
    var datePicker = $().datepicker({});
    var t;
    $(window).on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel scroll', function() {
        window.clearTimeout(t);
        t = window.setTimeout(function() {
            $('.datepicker-input').datepicker('place');
        }, 100);
    });
```

CSS:

```
html,body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.datepicker-input {
    margin-top: 250px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Link to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8C6jT/1/ (Thanks A. Wolff)

**EDIT:**

This function is some what effective in Chrome and IE.. it still causes the calendar to move away from the input box if you scroll too quickly but it doesn't work for Firefox.

Comment: why this `$().datepicker({});` ?

Comment: Fixed jsFiddle to replicate issue (using mousewheel e.g): http://jsfiddle.net/8C6jT/1/

Comment: What is the purpose of this timeout???

Comment: I was following this example: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20488734/bootstrap-datepicker-does-not-scroll-when-scrolling-the-modal

Comment: @zen_1991 Ok, makes sense then. Setting in this case BODY height will fix it: http://jsfiddle.net/8C6jT/2/  Now i'm wondering why `min-height` in percentage doesn't work in this case?!

Comment: ↑↑↑↑ Ok find it in spec: `If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the percentage value is treated as '0' (for 'min-height') or 'none' (for 'max-height').`

Comment: It fixed it on the jsfiddle but it doesnt on my page, so there must be more values such as min-height else where on the page that are throwing it off.

Comment: Check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8C6jT/4/

Comment: The fiddles referenced above do not work: datepicker does not appear?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why, but positioning is based on scrolling so you need to find this code in bootstrap-datepicker.js

```
scrollTop = $(this.o.container).scrollTop();
```

and rewrite it to

```
scrollTop = 0;
```

After that it will stay with input. Dont know if its the best solution, but using scroll events to fix it should not be the best because of cross browser and device support.

Answer (score 0):

**use your css like this..**

```
html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    min-height: 1000%;
}
.datepicker-input {
    margin-top: 250px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
.dropdown-menu {
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
html, body {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1000%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Hope this will help

Comment: There is JS is the background controlling events around the HTML and Body, this will be ineffective.