# Jquery custom ui datepicker scroll issue with bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

i am struggling for last near three hours with issue i have. 
So i have bootstrap modal, and within that there is a form. Everything is basic. Modal is longer then screen height so it needs to be scrolled.
Call of datepicker:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({ minDate: 0});
```

So datepicker pops like usually in correct place below or above input field depends on position at the time. But issue is when i start to scroll trough modal if datepicker is open, it stays on that same spot, while modal moves beneath it. Ive read its because it takes body as parent, so its FIXED positioned, and on scroll its modal scroll not body scroll.
I tried allot of combionations but just cant figure how to make it take modal as parent, or move with input field..
Here is fiddle with same issue. Appriciate any help.
Thanks alot

http://jsfiddle.net/csrA5/

Comment: Have you seen this question? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351871/jquery-date-picker-not-moving-with-page-scroll

Comment: oh my god :O
I opened like 30 threads, and didnt see that. I deserve ban for this. Thank you verry much Tokn

Comment: Ah well its not actually working, but at least is on the poing. Because if you scroll before clicking input, datepicker is dissplaced