# Stop datepicker from floating around

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with datepicker calendar floating around. I need to stop it from doing so. I need it to stay at the input box.

```
$('.date').datepicker({
  format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
  autoclose: true
});

$('.close-button').unbind();

$('.close-button').click(function() {
  if ($('.datepicker').is(":visible")) {
    $('.date').datepicker('hide');
  } else {
    $('.date').datepicker('show');
  }
});
```

Below is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/qgzwwt70/4/

Help.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? What do you mean by "stay at the input box"?

Comment: er...prevent the calendar from moving up down while scrolling. need the calendar to be stay below or locked at the input box (like when it first appeared).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351871/jquery-date-picker-not-moving-with-page-scroll

Comment: I believe that jquery-ui.css while the external resources I listed in fiddle are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the desired behavior by calculating the top offset of the date picker popup on window scroll.

```
$("#GIOCFModal").scroll(function(){

 if($('.datepicker-dropdown').length == 1)
 {
 if($('.date').offset().top > $('.datepicker-dropdown').offset().top)
 {
   var value = $('.date').offset().top  - 15 - $('.datepicker-dropdown').height();
 }
 else
 {
   var value = $('.date').offset().top + 35;
 }

 $('.datepicker-dropdown').offset({top:value})
 }

});
```

Working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/vLbphkq9/