# Jquery date plugin not working properly when it is used in accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker, jquery-ui-accordion

After clicking the date picker if i scroll the accordion content the expanded area of datepicker is not moving.

[Calendar not moving with the date after scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVLsm.png)

Comment: add a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) if you can...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Date picker not moving with page scroll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351871/jquery-date-picker-not-moving-with-page-scroll)

Comment: check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/x94h0tLt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638854/how-to-keep-jquery-ui-datepicker-in-place-stick-to-the-input-control-while-scr) post suggests, its a known problem while using datepicker in scrolable div....you can use the `.blur()` method on scroll event to make it look better..

**Just pasting the demo code from the previous post(in case that gets removed):**

```
var datePicker = $('#datepicker').datepicker();

$(".demo").scroll(function() {
  datePicker.datepicker('hide');
  $('#datepicker').blur();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  datePicker.datepicker('hide');
  $('#datepicker').blur();
});
```